# Java URL NTLM authentication fails on an endpoint that accepts both NTLM and Digest authentication

Tags: java, authentication, ntlm

I have an endpoint that accepts both NTLM and Digest authentication. This code appears to be attempting to fall back to Digest, rather than properly using NTLM:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

public class NT {

    static final String kuser = "[USERNAME]"; // your account name
    static final String kpass = "[PASSWORD]"; // retrieve password for your account 

    static class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            // I haven't checked getRequestingScheme() here, since for NTLM
            // and Negotiate, the usrname and password are all the same.
            System.err.println("Feeding username and password for " + getRequestingScheme());
            return (new PasswordAuthentication(kuser, kpass.toCharArray()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
        Authenticator.setDefault(new MyAuthenticator());
        URL url = new URL("http://sitethatneedsntlmauthentication");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        InputStream ins = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins));
        String str;
        while((str = reader.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Feeding username and password for Negotiate
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Feeding username and password for digest
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too man
y  times (20)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown S
ource)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown So
urce)
        at NT.main(nt.java:26)
```

The server is sending back the following accept headers:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="site.company.com", ... [other metadata]
```

If I try this against a URL that only accepts NTLM this code works fine, so I know the credentials are working.